# JQuery JSON from file to object

Tags: json, parsing, getjson

I copied this from the jquery site.  I'm trying to learn how to get json data to a web page.  The date has validated on: http://jsonlint.com/

The results from running the my script are:
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]

Do I need to parse the data or does getJSON do that.
This is the code I'm using:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
  var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
  });

  $('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('body');
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Troubleshooting tips would be great and of course an answer would be great too!

data.json

```
[
    {
        "bytes": "476.577044"
    },
    {
        "bytes": "136113.5289"
    },
    {
        "bytes": "118870.8151"
    },
    {
        "bytes": "55001.67852"
    }
]
```

console.log(data) response:

```
[Object { bytes="476.577044"}, Object { bytes="136113.5289"}, Object { bytes="118870.8151"}, Object { bytes="55001.67852"}]
JSON.html (line 14)
[Object { bytes="476.577044"}, Object { bytes="136113.5289"}, Object { bytes="118870.8151"}, Object { bytes="55001.67852"}]
JSON.html (line 14)
[Object { bytes="476.577044"}, Object { bytes="136113.5289"}, Object { bytes="118870.8151"}, Object { bytes="55001.67852"}]
JSON.html (line 14)
[Object { bytes="476.577044"}, Object { bytes="136113.5289"}, Object { bytes="118870.8151"}, Object { bytes="55001.67852"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty close, try this: (as long as the file "data.json" is a valid file)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
      var items = [];

      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
      });

      $('<ul/>').addClass('my-new-list').html(items.join('')).appendTo('body');
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

The way your json is setup, `$.each` is going to iterate the outer array containing the objects. Which makes the `key` a numeric index, and the `val` the actual object. With that said, changing the `$.each` part to look like this:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.bytes + '</li>');
});
```

should do the trick

(sidenote: id's should not begin with a number)

Comment: it has the same effect, plus, you didn't answer the question.

Comment: Same Result.  The data.json is a real file on the same server avoiding the cross domain stuff.  In the firebug I see the get response has the correct data in it, it just  churns out the [object Object] response for each JSON entry.

Comment: what does it output when you try to `console.log(data)` in your callback, mainly, what does your json look like

Comment: Thanks for the console.log(data) trick, it is indeed getting the correct information from the JSON file.

Comment: what does your json look like

Comment: it's just a console quirk indeed, you may also try `console.dir` or `console.debug` (on firebug).

Comment: @EliranMalka It's not firebug, his json probably looks like `[{foo:bar},{foo:bar}]`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved it by putting the JSONP object in `console.log()` and then looking at the tree in Chrome's developer tools. There I realized that "object" was just the name the parser gave to all the different objects inside the JSON file, so you have to account for that when fetching the values.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
      var items = [];

      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items.push('<li >' + data.object.bytes + '</li>');
      });

      $('<ul/>').addClass('my-new-list').html(items.join('')).appendTo('body');
    });
});
```

You data you want is in a key:value pair *inside* an object called "object which is inside an array(this is what is being cycled through when you do `$.each()`)

So you have to tell JQuery to look inside the object and *then* tell it what key to look up.

I didn't put any ID's as I'm not really sure what you wanted them to be. Did you just want every element to have "bytes" as the ID? ID's should be unique (at least according to this http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

If what you want is a `class` so that you can do CSS/JQuery over the whole batch then you could try something like `'<li class ="' + object.key + '">'`

Comment: To the OP, If this is the best answer, could you please mark it as such? Thanks.